# I'm new to Lua and have no idea what I could have possibly done wrong

Tags: text, lua, io

When running this part of a text adventure it always goes to the "invalid option" block even if you type in `1` or `2`.

```lua
print("Enter your name")
name = io.read()
print(name)
print("...")
print("your name kinda sucks ngl")
print("wanna drink some orange juice")
choice = io.read()

if choice == 1 then
    print("here is your orange juice")
    print("you better like it, i worked hard to pour the carton")
elseif choice == 2 then
    print("your loss then")
else
    print("invalid answer")
end
```

Comment: try `if choice == "1" ` . ps: screenshot - bad choice, use simple text code

Answer (score 0):

[`io.read()`](https://www.lua.org/pil/21.1.html) returns a string, `1` is a number. Equality does not convert between types automatically. You can either use `"1"` as Mike suggested or convert `choice` to a number using [`tonumber()`](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html). I recommend the former.

From the manual https://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html

> Equality (==) first compares the type of its operands. If the types are different, then the result is false.